# No module named X, even though it's there

Tags: python

When trying to run an app written in Python2, I run into an import error, but when looking into the files, they are all there?

All files related to python2-six:

```
python2-six /usr/
python2-six /usr/lib/
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg-info/
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg-info/top_level.txt
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc
python2-six /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyo
python2-six /usr/share/
python2-six /usr/share/licenses/
python2-six /usr/share/licenses/python2-six/
python2-six /usr/share/licenses/python2-six/LICENSE
```

Upon running the program:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configobj.py", line 22, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

My PYTHONPATH for Python2.7 is:

```
/usr/lib/python27.zip
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0
```

How come the module isn't picked up?
I should mention that I'm on Arch Linux, with Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 running side by side. With /usr/bin/python being symlinked to python3.

Comment: Open python 2.7 in interactive mode. Type ```help('modules')```. Can you see ```six``` listed there?

Comment: Try updating PATH environment variable with the respective python bin path like export PATH=/usr/bin/python:$PATH and try running it

Comment: @raj I can't see six listed there

Comment: @LakshmiBhavani that doesn't solve it

Comment: try to add the python path where your module is installed @Str-Gen

Comment: @Str-Gen that means ```six``` isn't installed in your python 2.7 environment. To install it in your python 2.7 environment you can do something like ```python2 -m pip install six```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means your environment isn't set up correctly.  There's more to a virtual environment than symlinking the `bin` path.

While in python 3 you can do `python -m venv venv_name`, in python 2 you need to create a virtual environment to run.

How did you create your virtualenv?

I would activate the environment; `source /path/to/bin/activate`.

Use `pip list` command and see what it says.

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv

Comment: So if you have python 2 installed, it has its own site-packages and you're trying to use a python 3 interpreter to do something else.  Its a kinda funky situation.  You should create a python 2 virtualenvironment if you want to run them side by side.  Thats why it doesn't work.

Comment: I specifically invoke the program with python2, that's not enough to make sure the right version's modules are used?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it is not.  If you're interested in what a virtualenv has going on , take a look at the activate script and see why its necessary.  You CAN use an interpreter in a virtualenv to, kinda, soft activate it, but still you have to have a virtualenv set up for that, still.